# What is the right way to access variables in laravel mailer function

Tags: php, laravel

Well this would be a simple question. I Want to know how I can access variables in the following mailer function.
I'm gonna fetch these values from the database and use it in the mailer function.
When I trying to access these variables directly into the mailer function it is saying `Undefined variable: to_email`

For the following code the variables are not being identified and an error is thrown.

```
$to_email = 'to_email@gmail.com';  
$to_firstname = 'Arun';  
$to_lastname = 'Singh';  

Mail::queue('/emails/test', array('firstname'=>'arun'), function($message){  
    $message->to($to_email, $to_firstname.' '.$to_lastname)->subject('Welcome '.$to_firstname.' to XYZ!');
});
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anonymous function may also inherit variables from the parent scope by passing them in `use()` the syntax is `use($foo, $bar, $baz, ...)`, in your case it would be :

```
$to_email = 'to_email@gmail.com';  
$to_firstname = 'Arun';  
$to_lastname = 'Singh';  

Mail::queue('/emails/test', array('firstname'=>'arun'), function($message) use ($to_email, $to_firstname, $to_lastname) {  
    $message->to($to_email, $to_firstname.' '.$to_lastname)->subject('Welcome '.$to_firstname.' to XYZ!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Op you need to bring the variables into the scope of 
`function($message)` using a callback with `use()`.

```
$to_email = 'to_email@gmail.com';  
$to_firstname = 'Arun';  
$to_lastname = 'Singh';  

Mail::queue('/emails/test', array('firstname'=>'arun'), 
      function($message) use ( $to_email, $to_firstname, $to_lastname ){  
           $message->to($to_email, $to_firstname.' '.$to_lastname)
                   ->subject('Welcome '.$to_firstname.' to XYZ!');
});
```

Alternatively you could also set these variables to a array if this is applicable and then reference only the array variable inside your mail function.

```
$new_array = [
    $to_email => 'to_email@gmail.com',  
    $to_firstname => 'Arun',  
    $to_lastname => 'Singh'
];

Mail::queue('/emails/test', array('firstname'=>'arun'), 
      function($message) use ( $new_array ){  
           $message->to( $new_array["to_email"],
                         $new_array["to_firstname"].' '.$new_array["to_lastname"]
                       );
           $message->subject('Welcome '.$new_array["to_firstname"].' to XYZ!');
});
```

This might be overkill for your specific question, however might be easier if you have large data sets to pass through, as you mentioned that you will be getting these values from the database.

Comment: Good explanation :). Thank you.